# Hidden Markov models and anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

In Shane's answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/942/application-of-wavelets-to-time-series-based-anomaly-detection-algorithms) he suggests that Hidden Markov Models can be used more successfully than wavelets for anomaly / change detection (it was a bit unclear -the topic he was addressing is anomaly detection, although he uses the words "change detection")

I am not very familiar with Hidden Markov Models, but as I understand it, they require a known Markov process (all states and transition probabilities known) and for each state a known set of emission probabilities. The really interesting thing that can be done with these is that given a sequence of emissions one can find the most likely sequence of states that would have led to those emissions.

Assuming that I am understanding HMM correctly (please correct me if I am wrong), how is this used for anomaly detection? How would one determine the underlying Markov process to use and the emission probabilities to use an HMM for anomaly detection?

Comment: In editing your post I replaced the word "emission" with "transition" because the term "emission probability" is not commonly used to describe Markov chains and I thought that you were probably referring to transition probabilities.  If that is wrong please make appropriate changes.

Comment: Emission probabilities are used in **hidden** Markov models and refer to the probability of an observation given a hidden state. Generally you have hidden state $X_i$ which is related to $X_{i-1}$ by **transition** probabilities and an observation $Y_i$ which is related to $X_i$ by **emission** probabilities. The $X_i$ are never observed and need to be inferred using Vitterbi algorithm or expectation maximisation if the transition probabilities also unknown.

Comment: Your understanding seems accurate to me. Anomaly detection is a bit too vague a term to answer the question accurately, could you give a concrete example of the data and the type of anomaly you want to detect? e.g., a single observation anomaly, a change-point in the system behaviour, ...  Also the specific algorithm usually used to infer the unknown parameters of a HMM is the *Baum-Welch algorithm*.

Comment: Then I shall fix my edit.

Comment: I successfully used the recursive CUSUM test (a generalized fluctuation test, see Kuan & Hornik 1995) which is also implemented in an R-package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html. Still, HMMs can be used to detect changes in time-series in a similar way (by looking at most likely sequence of states corresponding to the data).

Answer (score 1):

According to this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#Inference), there are many inference benefits you gain from a HMM. The first inference is the ability to assign a probability to any observation sequence $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_1,\ldots, Y_N)$ by marginalizing over the set of all possible hidden state sequences $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,\ldots, X_N)$:

$P(\mathbf{Y}) = \sum_{\mathbf{X}} P(\mathbf{X}) P( \mathbf{Y} \vert \mathbf{X} )$

This way, you can assign probabilities to observation sequences even in an on-line manner as observations arrive (using the very efficient [forward algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm)). An anomaly is an observation that is (*relatively*) highly unlikely according $P(\mathbf{Y})$ (a threshold can be used to decide). Of course, the value of $P(\mathbf{Y})$ grows smaller and smaller as $N$ increases. Many methods can be used to ***renormalize*** $P(\mathbf{Y})$ to keep it within the representable range of floating-point data types and enable meaningful thresholding. For example, we might use the following as an anomaly measure:

$\mathbb{A}_{N} = \log P(Y_N \vert Y_1,\ldots, Y_{N-1}) = \log \frac{P(Y_1,\ldots, Y_N)}{P(Y_1,\ldots, Y_{N-1})}$
$\mathbb{A}_{N} = \log P(Y_1,\ldots, Y_N) - \log P(Y_1,\ldots, Y_{N-1})$

Comment: Can you point the source of such renormalization techniques? It is not clear to me why this difference should correspond to anomaly.